# How to solve what y axis segment was clicked in LightningChart

Tags: c#, lightningchart

I've started using LightningChart in my real time monitoring application. In my app there are many y axis which use segmented layout (one y axis per segment):

```
mainChart.ViewXY.AxisLayout.YAxesLayout = YAxesLayout.Segmented;
```

My goal is that when you mouse click a segment, it gets larger compared to other segments (kinda like zoom effect) and the other segments gets smaller. When you click it again it goes back to normal.

I know I can change the size of the segments with:

```
mainChart.ViewXY.AxisLayout.Segments[segmentNumber].Height = someValue;
```

That takes care of the zooming effect.
Now the problem is that how can I solve which segment was actually clicked? I figured out that you get mouse position via MouseClick -event (e.MousePos) but that seem to give only the screen coordinates so i'm not sure that it helps.

I'm using the LightningChart version 8.4.2

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that getting mouse position via MouseClick event is the key here. The screen coordinates you get via e.GetPosition (not e.MousePos) can be converted to chart axis values with CoordToValue() -method. Then you just compare the y-coordinate to each y-axis minimum/maximum value to find out what segment was clicked. Here is an example:

```
_chart.MouseClick += _chart_MouseClick;

private void _chart_MouseClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{            
    var mousePos = e.GetPosition(_chart).Y;
    double axisPos = 0;
    bool isWithinYRange = false;
    foreach (AxisY ay in _chart.ViewXY.YAxes)
    {
        ay.CoordToValue((float)mousePos, out axisPos, true);
        if (axisPos >= ay.Minimum && axisPos <= ay.Maximum)
        {
            // Segment clicked, get the index via ay.SegmentIndex;
            isWithinYRange = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isWithinYRange)
    {
        // Not in any segment
    }
}
```

After finding out the segment index, you can modify its height as you described:

```
_chart.ViewXY.AxisLayout.Segments[0].Height = 1.5;
```

Note Height means segment height compared to other segments.
Hope this is helpful.